# How to create a MESSAGE BOX with user defined buttons in C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, messagebox

I wanted to create three buttons continue, exit and try again buttons.

```
MessageBox(NULL, "Loading.. Click ok to continue or Cancel to Exit",   "TITLE", MB_OKCANCEL);
```

How can i change the ok and cancel buttons to Continue and Exit??

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? People are not here to work out code for you...

Comment: IIRC you can use one of the [enumeration values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) explained. Otherwise you'd have to create your own dialog box.

Comment: In this case I'd use a `"Load resource FOO?" | YES | NO |` dialog. If it becomes more complex, use a [task dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: There is actually a way to do this, and it's quite C++/WinAPI-specific, so it doesn't really fit the .NET question, which is marked as a duplicate. See http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/messagebox/article.php/c10873/MessageBox-with-Custom-Button-Captions.htm
I think that this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot do this**. The `MessageBox` function does not offer this capability. It has a few stock message box types, but if you need custom texts other than those, you are out of luck.

You could always create your own custom dialog using the resource editor, of course.

Those are the message box types that are supported by `MessageBox`:

```
/*
 * MessageBox() Flags
 */
#define MB_OK                       0x00000000L
#define MB_OKCANCEL                 0x00000001L
#define MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE         0x00000002L
#define MB_YESNOCANCEL              0x00000003L
#define MB_YESNO                    0x00000004L
#define MB_RETRYCANCEL              0x00000005L
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
#define MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE        0x00000006L
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0500 */
```

Answer (score 0):

The MB_OKCANCEL parameter is the one that controls the buttons that are displayed.  You could try MB_RETRYCANCEL instead:

MessageBox(NULL, "Loading.. Click ok to continue or Cancel to Exit", "TITLE",MB_RETRYCANCEL);

Also, sometimes it is easier to change the question/text in your message box than it is to change the buttons themselves.

This link gives you more information on the MessageBox function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own dialog box, if your requirement does not match the one from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx , and in winproc you can decide what to do as different buttons pressed.